# Laravel Seeding Relationship issue

Tags: laravel, factory, relation, eloquent

I want to add data into `administrators` table for every data inserted into my `users` table. Here's`UserFactory.php`:

```
$factory - > define(App\ User::class, function(Faker $faker) {
  return [
    'id' => $faker - > unique() - > isbn10,
    'email' => $faker - > unique() - > safeEmail,
    'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
  ];
});
```

and my `AdministratorFactory.php`:

```
$factory - > define(App\ Administrator::class, function(Faker $faker) {
  return [
    'prn' => $faker - > unique() - > isbn10,
    'rfid_number' => $faker - > unique() - > isbn10,
    'first_name' => $faker - > firstName,
    'middle_name' => $faker - > lastName,
    'last_name' => $faker - > lastName,
    'role_id' => 1
  ];
});
```

and I have my `UsersTableSeeder.php`:

```
public function run() {
  factory(App\ User::class, 50) - > create() - > each(function($user) {
    $user - > administrator() - > save(factory(App\ Administrator::class) - > make());
  });
}
```

Whenever I execute `php artisan db:seed --class UsersTableSeeder`, the `user_id` in my `Administrator` table is always `0`. I am expecting to have `user_id` with the same `id` as `User` table has. They are both 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: You don't need to turn every piece of sample code into an snippet. And with more reason if it is php code that can't be run by the snippet engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the user_id for Administrator factory as:

```
$user->administrator()->save(factory(App\ Administrator::class)->make(['user_id' => $user->id ]));
```

Comment: Solved. Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an int automatically.